# Tables from multiple files to one variant Array

Tags: arrays, excel, while-loop, vba

I'm writing a process and using a while-loop to go through through all folders and excel files in a user specified directory.

My question is, I want to pull a certain set of data from each workbook and add them to one large array that I can perform calculations on after I have all my data grouped together in one array.  Would rather not dump all of this data to excel and calculate as it could be many thousands of rows.

I'm not sure how to amend the size of the array without deleting old data?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: I think `Redim` is what you are looking for to resize an array and preserve data.

Comment: Do I just redim the array as both the first and second table?  or do I have to define the size of both?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking about first and second table. I guest it depends on your logic and what you need to perform. Checkout this link as it will explain better [Dynamic Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716275(v=vs.60).aspx)